# Why woocommerce does not allows to add attachments with reviews?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, url-rewriting

I am working on a woocommerce based website and it does not accept attachments with reviews (though reviews without attachment works fine). It throws the following error, 
Oops! That page can’t be found.
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search? 
in `www.domainname.come/wp-comments-post.php` link.

I tried adding the following code to htaccess but it does not work,`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*EXAMPLE.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
```

`Can anyone help to fix this.. Thanks in advance..